# Unexpected issue with file uploads in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-3

I have 2 websites created with CodeIgniter on the same host. I've been using them without any issues for the past 3 years. I have several forms in various places for uploading images, using only PHP without AJAX and jQuery. When the file is uploaded without errors, it redirects to the same form page. This functionality has been working perfectly all these years.

Suddenly, 10 days ago, when I upload an image, the spinner on the browser tab freezes and keeps spinning as if it's still loading, even though the file has already been uploaded. It seems to hang just before the redirection. The file is in the folder, and the database record has been created.

If I refresh the page at that moment, the next file I upload works perfectly with the redirection, etc.

The strange thing is that I haven't made any changes to the page, PHP, MySQL, or anywhere else. I asked the host if there were any changes or upgrades, and they said no. I don't know where to look for the issue.

The problem is in Google chrome. I make some test in firefox and i think is work fine in firefox

Below, let's take a look at a snippet of the upload code I mentioned.

```
function upload_tameia_photos(){
    $time= time();
    $mt_rand = mt_rand(100,999);
    $id = $_POST["tameia_id"];

    $year = date('Y');

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img-tameia';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    //$config['encrypt_name'] = true;
    $config['max_size'] = '6048';
    $config['max_width'] = '8000';
    $config['max_height'] = '6000';
    $config['file_name'] = $year.'-'.$id.'-'.$mt_rand.$time;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $data['title'] = "Upload Files";
    
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photos')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('tameio_photo', $error);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $imgName = $this->upload->data();
        
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './assets/img-tameia/'.$imgName["file_name"];
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['quality'] = '80%';
        $config['width'] = 1000;
        $config['new_image'] = './assets/img-tameia/'.$imgName["file_name"];
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        
        $imgurl = $imgName["file_name"];
        $data = array(
            'ph_tameio_id'  => $id,
            'ph_tameia_url'   => $imgurl
        );

        $this->db->insert('phot_tameia', $data);
    }

    redirect(base_url().'reports/tameio_view/'.$id);
}
```

I didn't have many things to try. I tried using another browser and computer, and I also asked the host if there were any changes or upgrades, but nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What debugging have you tried?  "*The file is in the folder*" - this code creates 2 files, not 1, what about the 2nd?  GD resizing seems like a good candidate for something taking time too.  What if you comment out the resizing stuff, does the problem go away?  What about simply adding some log statements with timestamps at various points along the code, you could see where it hangs or what takes a long time?

Comment: [The `image_lib` docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html) state: "*Image processing can require a considerable amount of server memory for some operations. If you are experiencing out of memory errors while processing images you may need to limit their maximum size, and/or adjust PHP memory limits.*"  Have you checked your PHP and web server logs for errors to see if that is happening?

Comment: i raise memory limit but dont worked

Comment: i comment and the resize code, but the problem not solved